# Consuming Delphi TFDJSONDataSets in c#

Tags: c#, json, rest, delphi

We have built a JSON/REST server which communicates with a Firemonkey client (both written in Delphi 10).

Datasets sent by the server are consumed by the client like this:

```
procedure TrrClientModule.GetActiveUsers(const aCallingForm: TForm);
var
  LDataSetList: TFDJSONDataSets;
  LDataSet: TFDDataSet;
begin
  try
    LDataSetList := ServerMethods1Client.rr_GetActiveUsers;
    LDataSet := TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValueByName(LDataSetList,
      'Users');
    FDMemTableActiveUsers.Active := False;
    FDMemTableActiveUsers.AppendData(LDataSet);
    FDMemTableActiveUsers.Open;
  except
    On E: Exception do
      HandleException(E, aCallingForm);
  end;
end;
```

This works fine, but now I want to consume this data set in C#. How can this be done?

The result I find in C# is something like this:

```
eJx9Vm1XE0cUvusLIip...OzMbqN2opcg5Fj+Dpsf+wf4rtszMb\r\nmI3YcLLcmXm...eu/dtbi6PunqOiMxNopw==
```

How can we make it human readable in C#?

Comment: It is clearly base64 encoded. But it is not text when you decode it. Some binary data. Probably proprietary for this component. What does the documentation say?